# ms Access VBA using a string from another form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called RetailEntry that has two columns I'm attempted to use as a string for when my users hit a Review button built into a separate form that pops up.

The following is a very simplified version of my code:

```
Private Sub ReviewButton_Click()
Dim strSeason As String
Dim strType As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSeason = Forms!RetailEntry.Season.Value
strType = Forms!RetailEntry.Offer.Value
End Sub
```

When I click my review button I keep getting the error message "Invalid Use of Null" on my strings
`strSeason = Forms!RetailEntry.Season.Value strType = Forms!RetailEntry.Offer.Value`
but it shouldn't be seeing a null/blank as these are fields that are filled out in the form RetailEntry.

What happens next in the code (the part you don't see) is a string that setups up a SQL query uses the strSeason, and strType based on what was entered in the RetailEntry form under the corresponding fields.

I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that my Review button is it's own form but I'm not sure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use Forms!RetailEntry!Season.Value instead of using the . between Entry and Season?

Comment: "I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that my Review button is it's own form but I'm not sure." then use "Me." to reference yourself

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I get an error that says "Microsoft Access cannot find the referenced form 'RetailEntry'.

Comment: @JulioGadioliSoares if I use `strSeason = Me.Season.Value` I get an error saying that the "method or data member not found"

Comment: You're right. Use `Forms("RetailEntry").Season`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz same error.

Comment: AFAIK, presented code should work, however, there are other ways to pass data between forms: 1) OpenArgs of OpenForm and 2) global variables or TempVars.

Comment: @June7 This code works as long as I keep it in the RetailEntry form, but the moment I move it to the ReviewButton form with the RetailEntry Form as a subform it errors out. I guess I'll just have to keep messing with it. I was hoping it would be something easy I was missing.

Comment: Your narrative did not state you are trying to reference a subform. That does change things.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with the following lines:

```
strSeason = [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Season].Value
strType = [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Offer].Value
```